How can I get Authorization Code for eBay API programmatically?
I have recently joined eBay and signed up a developer account. I want to integrate eBay APIs to my PHP Laravel Website. I need access token to call different APIs and to get an access token first I need to get an authorization code which will be provided in next API call to get an access code. I see there is an option to get authorization code where Application Keys are, by creating a user and giving consent to login to my application, which returns authorization code. But I want to do that programmatically as I am a developer and I want some way like an API where I can get authorization code. I did not find it in documentation. I don't know if I am missing something here. Is there some Postman Collection with these calls?
There are OAuth client libraries for Android, C#, Java, Node.js and Python but none can be found for PHP.
Following is the link of doc I am following:
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-authorization-code-grant.html

The whole OAuth process is HTTP-based, so nothing is stoping you from implementing it yourself. If you want to use a library to help with the basic stuff, https://oauth.net/code/php/

That will redirect to HTML page to get consent from user. There are oauth client libraries provided for ebay. Isn't there some way to achieve this to hit API using cron jobs?

"That will redirect to HTML page to get consent from user." - yes, because that's how OAuth mainly works. "Isn't there some way to achieve this to hit API using cron jobs?" - no, that is only possible for the client credentials grant flow. But whether a token you get from that would be enough to perform the action you want, depends on what you actually want to do.

No, it's not possible to generate the authorization code grant token without obtaining user consent. You must secure the user's consent at least once because generating a user access token is contingent upon it.
For further details, please consult the API documentation here:
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-auth-code-grant-request.html
The authorization code grant process yields a refresh_token, which has a lengthy lifespan. You can utilize this token to renew an expired user access token, eliminating the need to repeatedly seek the user's consent for a new token. Simply store the refresh_token for future use.
For a comprehensive understanding, delve into the Refresh Token API documentation:
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-refresh-token-request.html
Credits:
https://developer.ebay.com/support/kb-article?KBid=5220

I did find that article. Thanks anyway.
